# Import classes into one main file shows error

Tags: javascript, html

I create many js classes and wanna import all of them to one `main.js` file where I want to invoke all of methods from these classes I need. Then, I want to use this `main.js` script in my `index.html` website file.
But shows me error like this: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` in console for every method I want to use. I do not think that it's a problem with paths but I do not have any idea how to solve this.

`main.js` class

```
import NavigationAnimation from "./dom/navigation";

NavigationAnimation.stickyNav();
```

`NavigationAnimation` class

```
export default class NavigationAnimation {
  //code
}
```

files structure is like this:

[image]

and my `index.html` is like that

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
    </main>
</body>

<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Can anybody explain what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `import` statement isn't being transpiled so needs to be the full filename, *including the extension,* just like the call for `main.js`:

```js
import NavigationAnimation from './dom/navigation.js' // <- add '.js' here
```

Also consider using the [`.mjs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#aside_%E2%80%94_.mjs_versus_.js) extension.